# How to drop all contents like Tables, Packages, Indexes, Sequences, LOB all these at one time from user

Tags: oracle, plsql

I create one user name as **MD**. Unfortunately I copy the database from **SYS** to user **MD** using **SQL developer**. SO that lots of Tables, Indexes, Sequences, Objects and lot more has been copied. I want to delete all these at one time. How it is possible, While i tried to delete but not all has to be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have grant to 'DROP USER', You can drop MD user with this command:

```
DROP USER MD CASCADE;
```

and create MD user again.

Otherwise, You can make drop commands with following select:

```
SELECT 'DROP ' || T.OBJECT_TYPE || ' ' || T.OBJECT_NAME || ';' || CHR(10) COMMANDS
FROM USER_OBJECTS T
WHERE T.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'VIEW', 'PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY', 'TRIGGER');
```

You can add or remove object types in where clause.